# Save incoming mail attachment files in separate folder?

Tags: asp.net

Save incoming mail attachment files in separate folder for Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

You can label the mails which has attachment - Gmail does not store separate files. 
Here is how do you collect under a label ("folder") your mails with attachment:

- Settings / Filter / Create new filter
- Check has attachment
- Apply label ''my-mails-with-attachments''

Comment: After you set up the rule, it will be applied automatically to your incoming mail.